# How to get minand max value in bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how to get min and max value in boot strap slider. and those value i need to assign in a input box 
My jquery code

```
 $('#bugetSlide').slider()
 .on('slide', function (ev) {
alert($('#bugetSlide').slider("option", "min"));
$("#minval").val(ev.values[0]);   
    });
```

My html code

```
 <input type="text" id="bugetSlide" data-slider-value="[250,450]" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-min="10" value="" class="span2" style="">
<input type="text" id="minval" readonly=readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .on('slideStop', function (ev) {
       var min = ev.value[0];
       var max = ev.value[1];          
       $("#minval").val(ev.value[0]);
       $("#maxval").val(ui.values[1]);        

   });
```

Comment: I think you need to correct that last line to  $("#maxval").val(ev.value[1]);